# Make auto key and mouse press on activate window on Python

Tags: python, mouse, autokey

I want to write an app in Python on Windows to do some jobs repeatedly.

For example, I need to convert some files into other type. I have a software installed in Windows to do that. However, that program was designed to do it file by file. Now I want to do it automatically.

Therefore, I need to write a software to simulate the key press on active windows. There are a lot of code on autokeyboard but it only works in terminal which run Python script. Specially, after I run Python script, I minimize the terminal, then open some program then the Python script will simulate the key press and/or mouse click in this program.

I found a lot of program can do something like hotkey and after press hotkey, it will simulate some key press and mouse. So I think it is possible.

Could anyone give me a solution for that?

Thanks.

Comment: it is unlikely you get an answer, if you don't show what you already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you to automate:

for mouse clicks:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(1319, 45)
pyautogui.scroll(200)
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrlleft", "a")
```

For keyboard

```
import keyboard
# It writes the keys r, k and endofline
keyboard.press_and_release('shift + r, shift + k, \n')
keyboard.press_and_release('R, K') 
# it blocks until esc is pressed 
keyboard.wait('esc')

# It records all the keys until escape is pressed
rk = keyboard.record(until='Esc')

# It replay back the all keys
keyboard.play(rk, speed_factor=1)
```

Comment: I tried this one before, but it is only click and write to the terminal which I run Python into it. The active window of "MS Paint" for example, doesnot receipt any key and click.

Comment: This is just an example with which you can try it. Provide proper coordinates and it will click on that co ordinate. I have tried it.

Comment: I found that why it was not work. I add some sleep time and it works now. Thanks.